# Multiple "uses-permissions" in manifest when build with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, manifest

i need some help regarding AndroidManifest's "uses-permissions".

I have a Cordova project, with some plugins.
When i launch `cordova run android` i get this error:

```
Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-79 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:32:5-79
[...]
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I noticed that `uses-permission` in `plugin.xml` (inside each plugin's folder), triggers separately for each plugins, adding their permissions instead merging them in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This is my Manifest. As you can see, `uses-permissions` are duplicated: [1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/kafXb.png

Plugins folder is autogenerated when i add plugins, so i need a solution "outside" this folder, this means that i don't want to manually edit `plugin.xml` inside folders.

In `config.xml`, i've added this:

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/uses-permission[@android:name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION']">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

then i've ran:

```
cordova platform rm android
rm -r package-lock.json
rm -r node-modules (folder)
rm -r plugins (folder)
```

then

```
npm install
cordova platform add android
```

But then, when i run `cordova run android` again, permissions are still duplicated.

My stack:

```
Cordova Packages:

    cli: 11.0.0
        common: 4.0.2
        create: 4.0.0
        lib: 11.0.0
            common: 4.0.2
            fetch: 3.0.1
            serve: 4.0.0

Project Installed Platforms:

    android: 10.1.2

Environment:

    OS: macOS Monterey 12.4
    Node: v14.19.3
    npm: 6.14.17
```

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the permission inside the permission node. Change your xml to

```
 <platform name="android">
     <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     </config-file>
 </platform>
```